# How to select columns in a manytomany relationship in gorm postgresql

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have a model like this

```
type User struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID      `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid()"`
    Name string `json:"name" gorm:"unique"`
    Jobs []JobUser `json:"jobs" gorm:"foreignKey:UserID;default:null"`
}
```

The model between User and Jobs looks like this

```
type JobUser struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID      `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid()"`
    JobID uuid.UUID      `json:"job_id"`
    UserID uuid.UUID      `json:"user_id"`
}
```

and lastly, this is what the job model looks like

```
type Job struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID      `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid()"`
    Name      string         `json:"name" gorm:"unique"`
    Users     []JobUser  `json:"-" gorm:"foreignKey:JobID"`
}
```

im trying to query the contents of jobs from user, the response struct type should look like this

```
type User struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID      `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid()"`
    Name string `json:"name" gorm:"unique"`
    Jobs []Job `json:"jobs"`
}
```

this is how i do it with gorm

```
if err := db.DB.Preload("Jobs").Find(&roles).Error; err != nil {
    return
}
```

but then this returns User with the model inbetween, which is not what i want

how can i return User with Job model directly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return `User` with `Job` model directly without the `JobUser`, you should use the gorm preload function with a custom query, something like this;

```
var users []User

if err := db.DB.Preload("Jobs").Find(&users).Error; err != nil {
    return err
}
```